# Are there any languages with second-person pronouns marked for a proximal/distal distinction?

Tags: linguistic-typology, list-of-languages, pronouns

I am curious if there are any natural languages where the personal pronoun used to refer to the addressee varies in some way depending on their distance to the speaker. For instance, one form might be used when conversing with someone in the same room, while another would be used in a letter delivered to a distant recipient.

By the nature (until recently) of long-distance communication, such a distinction could also be construed in terms of temporal distance (whether the composition and reception of the message are simultaneous or separated by a delay) or indirection (whether the recipient will hear the message from the speaker's mouth, or indirectly by some other means).

Just to clarify what I am saying:

- I am not talking about proximal/distal distinctions in *third-person* pronouns, nor in demonstratives (e.g. proximal/medial/distal systems).
- I am not talking about *social* proximity/distance insofar as such a distinction might be better analyzed as a matter of formality or politeness, although a language with both features might conflate physical and social distance in forming pronouns.

I would be particularly interested in languages where this distinction is *obligatory*, i.e. languages which posses no distance-neutral second person pronouns, or if they do, do not permit such pronouns to substitute for distance-sensitive pronouns in all contexts. Thanks!

Comment: Your second paragraph doesn’t seem like a matter of logical course to me. Spatial distance to the addressee would entail temporal distance in the case of letters and similar media, but proximate/distal can also be something as simple as whether the person is right next to you or in the next room or out in the garden, in which case there’s no significant temporal distance.

Comment: Japanese has, historically, had something sort of like this, with the demonstratives こなた/そなた/あなた _konata/sonata/anata_ (= proximal/close to listener, medial/close to speaker, distal/far from both) all doubling as personal pronouns for the second person. It’s not quite that simple, though, since they’ve also doubled as pronouns for the first and third persons in fairly non-obvious ways: medial _sonata_ seemingly only 2p, distal _anata_ 2/3p, and proximal _konata_ all of 1/2/3p.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh, very interesting - I was aware of that triplet but not its history - do you know of any references that elaborate on the historical implications/usage of these three as personal pronouns? My understanding is that in modern Japanese the distinction between them as such is largely in politeness.

Re: the second paragraph, yeah, I didn't mean to imply each distinction would be completely equivalent, just that there would be enough overlap for me to be interested in any of them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I’m not really. I just vaguely knew that I’m always a little wary when I see one of them used pronominally, because I’m never _quite_ sure who they’re referring to. I know that at least some of the demonstrative/person combinations are archaic or historical, but I don’t know what the actual chronology is – it may be that there has never been any full synchronic ambivalence between all three persons. Might be worth asking on [japanese.se] for more details.

Comment: In German, you can use "du da" (you there) when addressing someone who is more distant (it sounds somewhat impolite, too). But I don't think this counts as a grammatical form.